# Convert 3D(x,y,z) to 2D(x,y) (orthogonal) along its direction

Tags: visual-c++, unmanaged, 3d, curve, directx-9

I have gone through all available study resources in the internet as much as possible, which are in form of simple equations, vectors or trigonometric equations.
 I couldn't find the way of doing following thing:

Assuming Y is up in a 3D world.
I need to draw two 2D trajectories orthogonally (not the projections) for a 3D trajectory, say **XY-plane** for side view of the trajectory **w.r.t. the trajectory itself** and XZ-plane for top view for the same.

I have all the 3D points of the 3D trajectory, initial velocity, both the angles can be calculated by vector mathematics.

How should I proceed further?

refer:
Below a curve in different angles, which can loose its significance if projected along XY-plane. All I want is to convert the red curve along itself, the green curve along green curve and so on. and further how would I map side view to a plane. Top view is comparatively easy and done just by taking X and Z ordinates of each points.

I mean this the requirement. :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it is some thing to do with interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand the question, but I'll answer my interpretation anyway.

You have a 3D trajectory described by a sequence of points p<sub>0</sub>, ..., p<sub>N</sub>. We are given an angle v for a plane P parallel to the Y-axis, and wish to compute the 2D coordinates (d<sub>i</sub>, h<sub>i</sub>) of the points p<sub>i</sub> projected onto that plane, where h<sub>i</sub> is the *height* coordinate in the direction Y and d<sub>i</sub> is the *distance* coordinate in the direction v. Assume p<sub>0</sub> = (0, 0, 0) or else subtract p<sub>0</sub> from all vectors.

Let p<sub>i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, z<sub>i</sub>). The height coordinate is h<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i</sub>. Assume the angle v is given relative to the Z-axis. The vector for the direction v is then r = (sin(v), 0, cos(v)), and the distance coordinates becomes d<sub>i</sub> = dot(p<sub>i</sub>, r).

Comment: You have understood my problem perfectly. \m/  I trying to visualize 3rd paragraph. I'll be back. ( And I wonder I could explain in ur way. )